# SQL Server drop foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to drop a foreign key constraint but I am getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

And this is what I have as far as code:

```
ALTER TABLE SALE
    DROP CONSTRAINT SaleFK      FOREIGN KEY(SaleCustID)
                                REFERENCES  BUYER (BuyerID)
                                ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The answer is probably pretty obvious but it has been a long day...

Comment: `ALTER TABLE SALE DROP CONSTRAINT SaleFK` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

You don't want any of the extra info just the constraint name.

```
ALTER TABLE SALE DROP CONSTRAINT SaleFK;
```

Comment: Alternatively, `ALTER TABLE SALE DROP FOREIGN KEY SaleFK;`